# Formatting an html email signature for Outlook

Tags: html, css, image, fonts

im really new to code and have basic knowledge but can someone help. I've created code for an email but the layout changes when i add it to a signature. The social media icons, along with the font style change location and width.  My code is this:

```
<table style="border-color: #FFFFFF;">
<tbody>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<td style="padding: 0 10px 0 0px;" valign="top">
<div class="row">
  <div class="column"><a href="http://groupcis.com/" target="_blank"><img  width="100" height="140" src="https://f.hubspotusercontent00.net/hubfs/2255457/CIS.png" style="float: centre;" width="70" height="60" /><div style="padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px;">
  
  <div class="row" style= width"100%">
  <div class="column" style="float: left; padding: 1px; display: table;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/cisgroupemea" target="_blank"><img src="https://f.hubspotusercontent00.net/hubfs/2255457/Icons/Social%20Media%20Icons/2020%20Email%20signature/Facebook%2020x20.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a></div>
  <div class="column" style="float: left; padding: 1px;  display: inline-block;"><a href="https://twitter.com/group_cis" target="_blank"><img src="https://f.hubspotusercontent00.net/hubfs/2255457/Icons/Social%20Media%20Icons/2020%20Email%20signature/Twitter%2020x20.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a></div>
  <div class="column" style="float: left; padding: 1px; display: table;"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/computer-information-systems/" target="_blank"><img src="https://f.hubspotusercontent00.net/hubfs/2255457/Icons/Social%20Media%20Icons/2020%20Email%20signature/LinkedIn%2020x20.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a>
</div>
<div class="column" style="float: left; padding: 1px;  display: table;"><a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=9614525187&text=&source=&data=&app_absent=" target="_blank"><img src="https://f.hubspotusercontent00.net/hubfs/2255457/Icons/Social%20Media%20Icons/2020%20Email%20signature/Whatsapp%2020x20.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a>
</div></div>



<td style="border-left: 3px solid #2E6FAB; padding: 0 4px 0 4px;" valign="center">
</td>

  <div class="column"> <td style="padding: 0 18px 0 8px;" valign="top">
<div class="column"> <div class="column"><span style="color: #2E6FAB; font-size: 19px; font-family: 'segoe ui';">Your full name</span> &nbsp;</div>
<span style="color: #898989; font-size: 14px; font-family: 'segoe ui'; font-weight: bold;">Your Position</span><br>
<div><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #2E6FAB; font-family: 'segoe ui';">Mob:</span> <span style="color: #898989; font-size: 11px; font-family: 'segoe ui';"> Your mobile number - if you do not have one, remove section</span> <br><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #2E6FAB; font-family: 'segoe ui';">Tel:</span><span style="color: #898989; font-size: 11px; font-family: 'segoe ui';"> Your office number - if you do not have one, remove section</span> <br> <span style="font-size: 11px; color: #2E6FAB; font-family: 'segoe ui';">Skype:</span><span style="color: #898989; font-size: 11px; font-family: 'segoe ui';"> Your Skype Name</span><br /> <span style="font-size: 11px; color: #2E6FAB; font-family: 'segoe ui';">Email:</span> <span style="color: #898989; font-size: 11px; font-family: 'segoe ui';">Your Email</span></div>
</div>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</div>
</div>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. To debug I would recommend a really cool website : http://playcode.io/ Just place your HTML, CSS and JS and debug on the fly. However, I will look into your code and try to see how I can help

Comment: Need some point of clarification: What do you mean by `change` ? Like when you try to resize then things shift and adjust accordingly? If so that's called responsiveness and its there by design to accommodate your webpage based on display screens on which your page is being viewed